# Format string if not null

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a situation where I need to output, via CSV (Tab-delimited), a dataset of information.

Problem is that if the column value contains a value, then it needs to be double quoted.

The value types, could range from Alpha-Numeric strings to DateTime formatted values.

Was wondering if there was easier way than this:

```
(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(evt.Name)?null:string.Format("\"{0}\"", evt.Name))
```

for each value that is being exported to string value.

### Edit 2013-07-08 11:06 CST (modified 11:17 CST)

```
public string QuoteFormat(object val)
{
    if(val != null) {
        if(val == typeof(string))
            val = (val as string).Replace("\"" , "\"\"");

        return string.Format("\"{0}\"" , val);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Not really, that's pretty simple.

Comment: tbh, I see no problem with that solution.

Comment: @SamLeach wasn't sure if there was a LINQ format that gets same action done or not.  I try to keep it simple to execute and read for after-me developers.

Comment: If you need to execute this code multiple time, then you can make an extension method and use that.

Comment: If you're working with something moderately substantial like datasets, I'd be worried if any of the after-you developers struggle to read that.

Comment: @GoldBishop Linq works well with collections and everything. But in this case, you do not want to work with a collection of `char`. LINQ is nice and fun, but it's not the best tool all the time.

Comment: If there's a bigger picture here you could look at using something like [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) (LGPL), which would help you abstract out some of that formatting code.

Comment: Ended up taking the pattern above and making it into its own function.  Check the edit for the signature.

Comment: @GoldBishop Your edit will throw an error when `val` is null in: `return val.ToString()`

Comment: so should I `string?` or just `return val`?  So why is that when `String.Format` executes, it just returns `""` without erroring out?

Comment: If it's possible that your object is a string containing a quote character (or a value whose string representation returned by ToString() may contain a quote character), you'll need to consider some way of escaping such quotes (e.g. replace each quote by two quotes).

Comment: @GoldBishop What you wanted is to return `null` if the string (or object) is `null`. Just return `null` at that point

Comment: what you think of the current version of the method?

Comment: @GoldBishop I feel you should make use of method overloading. You could have a `QuoteFormat(string val)` living alongside of  `QuoteFormat(object val)`. That will remove the need to check for the type.

Comment: I will agree but as I don't have ultimate code control.  I will be monitoring the code cause if this occurs again, then it will most definitely be going into an Extension, if not a simple Helper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked if there was a way to express your problem more clearly. While your own code is good and that we do not see a problem with it, I'll suggest you to use an extension.

```
public static class GoldBishopExtensions
{
    public static string Transform(this string source, Func<string, string> transform, string fallback = null)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source) 
                   ? transform(source) 
                   : fallback;
    }
}
```

And then use it with:

```
// Return "evt.Name" if String is not null or whitespaces
// return null otherwise
evt.Name.Transform(name => String.Format("\"{0}\"", name));
```

Or:

```
// Return ("evt.Name") if String is not null or whitespaces
// return (No Value) otherwise
evt.Name.Transform(name => String.Format("\"{0}\"", name), "No Value");
```

But as stated in the comments, you do not *really* need this as you code is good as it is.

**Edit:** for your own specific problem, you extension could be:

```
public static class GoldBishopExtensions
{
    public static string Quote(this string source, string fallback = null)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source) 
                   ? String.Format("\"{0}\"", source) 
                   : fallback;
    }
}

evt.Name.Quote();
```

Comment: good call.  If I find myself doing this against outside of the exporter, I will definitely extract the pattern up a level so its available to all locations, for use.

Comment: I would push the format into the extention itself, just to reduse the amout of copied code if the same Transform needs to be done in several places.  Or I would at least use `name` inside the lambda as well `String.Format("\"{0}\"", name)`

Comment: @Cemafor evt.Name in the lambda was a typo. Fixing it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I made a small adjustment to the function you posted, if `val` is `null`, just return `""`.  This explicity states that you want no charactors if `val` is `null`.

```
public string QuoteFormat(object val)
{
    if(val != null) {
        // This is fine if there is an additional requirement to double existing quotes
        if(val == typeof(string))
            val = (val as string).Replace("\"" , "\"\"");

        // if you are using dates and the default format is fine, then this will work.
        // otherwise I would suggest formatting the date before passing in and perhaps
        // changing the parameter to string
        return string.Format("\"{0}\"" , val);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return null you can place a string null for letting you know the result was null:

```
string result = String.Format("\"{0}\"", evt.Name ??"null");//output -> "null"
//string result = String.Format("\"{0}\"", evt.Name ??null);// output -> ""
```

Comment: nah, if its null then I need the tab characters to be next to each other in the file `\t\t`, for instance.

Comment: can you provide an string example of what you really mean for example the result should be if not null "something" or \something\,and null should be "" or something else?

Comment: Doubt it will show up correctly but here is a partial set of data with mix types: `"6/4/2014 10:00:00 PM" 15 0 "active"        "Webinar"`

Comment: but is that string evt.name? or evt.name is a part of that string like the part "active",meaning evt.name has to be inserted into that string or the is it the whole string evt.name?

Comment: its not a nullable value from `evt.name` but strings dont need to be nullable as they are inherintly nullable by nature of their type.  Null for strings is nothing more than 0 length string.